# Reading from an SPI bus using the ESP-IDF (ESP32) and an ILI9341 display adapter. Not getting meaningful data

Tags: c, esp32, spi, esp-idf

I'm having trouble reading from an SPI bus, specifically an ILI9341 display adapter (i've had the same trouble with other devices as well though). When I attempt to read, all I ever get back are zeroes. I can write just fine.

I am using an ESP-WROVER-KIT v4.1 with an integrated ILI9341 display, so I know the wiring is correct. According to the documentation my configured MISO line is correct. Again, I write data just fine, so MOSI is good as well.

Basically, I set the address window, initiate a memory read (0x2E) and read a dummy parameter (which is always zero for me) and then read data. This is being done as separate transactions. When I write this way I have no trouble (except there is no dummy parameter on writes). Unfortunately, again I get zeroes when I read.

The complete code for reproducing this is as short as I can make it and yet too long for this forum, so I'm posting a link to the relevant .c file here that will reproduce the problem.

https://github.com/codewitch-honey-crisis/ili9341_read_rep/blob/master/src/main.c

That repo also contains a full platformio project if you need to run it. Just back up to the main repo link.

Here is an excerpt of the code.

```
spi_device_handle_t handle;
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(spi_bus_add_device(HOST,&devcfg,&handle));
init_display(handle);
uint16_t fill[320];
memset(fill,0xFF,320*2);
set_window(handle,0,0,319,239);
uint8_t cmd = 0x2C; // memory write
send(handle,&cmd,1,true);
for(int y=0;y<240;++y) {
    send(handle,(uint8_t*)fill,320*2,false);
}
set_window(handle,0,0,319,239);
cmd = 0x2E; // memory read
send(handle,&cmd,1,true);
// dummy read (see datasheet)
retr(handle,&cmd,1,false);
printf("dummy value: 0x");
print_hex(&cmd,1);
printf("\r\n");
// getting zeroes here, but expect FFFFFF...
for(int y=0;y<240;++y) {
    size_t sz = retr(handle,(uint8_t*)fill,320*2,false);
    print_hex((uint8_t*)fill,sz);
    printf("\r\n");
    vTaskDelay(1);
}
```

Here's how I set up the read (the retr() function)

```
// retrieves data from the SPI bus MISO line
// this doesn't seem to return meaningful data currently
size_t retr(spi_device_handle_t handle, uint8_t* data,size_t size,bool cmd) {
    if(0<size) {
        spi_transaction_t t;
        memset(&t,0,sizeof(t));
        // always use rx_buffer
        t.rx_buffer = data;
        t.length = t.rxlength = 8*size;
        t.user = (void*)!cmd;
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(spi_device_polling_transmit(handle,&t));
        return (t.rxlength+7)/8;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a link to the datasheet for reference
https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/ILI9341.pdf
The relevant pages are 116 and 117.
I do not think the datasheet will uncover the core issue but I'm providing it anyway. I think the issue is the way I'm calling the API, but I can't be sure. There are no good examples of reads in the ESP-IDF SDK except from an NVS thing which uses an entirely different SPI configuration (10 command bits, address bits, HALF_DUPLEX flag, etc) so it's not very useful to me.

I've also tried looking at Arduino code to do this but the SPI API is too different for me to make heads or tails of it enough to translate it to the ESP-IDF

Perhaps my code above needs some minor corrections? I'm hoping that's the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know this specific hardware, but the very first thing to check when troubleshooting SPI is clock phase and polarity settings, most commonly named CPOL and CPHA or similar. The master's settings need to correspond with what the slave expect. Otherwise you get "clock skew" which results in weird and subtle error phenomenon. One such symptom could be that writing works fine but reading doesn't.

Comment: I think you might be referring to the SPI mode? I'm not sure, as I don't recall those terms. I do know that the device operates at mode 0, and that is what my code is set for. In fact, I'm reasonably confident in the SPI configuration since the (public domain) code it came from initially was provided as a sample for this particular hardware by the hardware vendor.

Comment: I refer to the SPI hardware peripheral in your microcontroller. You'll have clock setup somewhere together with baudrate and similar. If you didn't write the driver, then you might have to dig through it. In general I'm always very suspicious about software-anything provided by hardware vendors.

Comment: Oh yeah, the clock speed is matched. No "dummy bits" either. The driver is spec'd for 10MHz but writes @ up to 26MHz with no issues in practice. I have it set to 10MHz as per the specs =)

Comment: Brief google revealed this: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/spi_master.html Apparently they are referred to as "launch edge" and "latch edge" here (which is weird). Another brief google of your display suggests the clock idles high then goes low and it clocks in the middle of the clock pulse. I always forget what's what, but my take is CPOL=1, CPHA=0 for this part. See SPI on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface. You have to find out how these are set in the MCU.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately after searching I can only figure out how to configure those in slave mode, not master mode. I'm not even sure what it's using presently. I think I'll need to hook a logic probe up to this. I'm waiting on a decent one to arrive. I was hoping that wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Yeah it's pretty much impossible to work with SPI without a logic analyser/multi-channel scope.

Comment: I've got one but it's garbage. My new one is a saleae logic pro 8 with buffer for days and decent software. we'll see how it stacks up when it arrives. I found out I may not be able to use the esp-idf's user-level API for this. I may have to go deeper to the next layer, which is undocumented. I hope not. There be dragons.

Comment: @Lundin, ILI9341 is quite famous panel controller, it uses normal mode. My take from the SPI debugging that the first thing to check is CS.

Comment: as in the OP, the display is integrated on board with this esp32. the CS line, MISO and MOSI lines are all correct.